# Difference between $(some_selector).css('pointer-events', 'none') and $(some_selector).css('pointer-events', ''); //Empty string as value

Tags: jquery

I was looking at some code and could not understand:

```
  $(some_selector).css('pointer-events',''); //Empty string as value
```

It does not seem to have the effect of:

```
  $(some_selector).css('pointer-events','none');
```

So, what does it do?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: `""` is never the same as `"none"` - try `console.log("" === "none")` - "none" is a specific instruction to stop there from being pointer events, without an instruction (`""`) it will revert to the parent/container's value or `auto`.

Comment: @freedomn-m I know that "none" is not the same as "" but it is how JQuery's internal code treats 'none' and 'empty' string that is relevant. Perhaps, the same? But I did not see that.

Comment: It would be like asking why `.css("background-color", "")` isn't the same as `.css("background-color", "red")`.

Comment: Yes, sometimes jquery "translates" one value to another, eg "fast" = "200" (for animations).   In this case, empty string is not translated to "none" as they have different meanings.   eg `$(some_selector).css('pointer-events','empty');` would not work the same as "none" even though, in English, empty and none are sort-of synonyms like empty and "".  But no, "none" is not a synonym for "empty" or "" for `pointer-events`.

Comment: @freedomn-m  Your comments are certainly informative and points are relevant. However, dumb as it may sound, the question still persists: Does jquery define behaviour for empty string as CSS value? Either way, I will accept your comments as answer if you post one.  In my case, it was interpreting it as 'auto'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does jquery define behaviour for empty string as CSS value?

Generally, no.

There are no* default *translations* in jquery.

In the case of `pointer-events` the *css default* (not jquery default) would be `auto`, so setting `""` would be the same as setting `"auto"`.

In the case of none vs "" - there's a difference between `none` (no setting) and `"none"` (the string "none")

(* as a rule, there's bound to be exceptions)